# Let $Q$ be a prime ideal of an integral domain $A$. Is $A[X]_{Q[X]}$ some localisation of $A_Q[X]$ ?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, localization

Let $A$ be an integral domain and $Q$ be a prime ideal of $A$. Then $Q[X]$is a prime ideal of $A[X]$.  My question is : Is $A[X]_{Q[X]}$ some localisation of $A_Q[X]$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is the localization at $QA_Q[X]$.